# how can I receive a string variable in a vfp and print it in BRL currency format

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a function that makes this mask of the Brazilian currency in the controller, but I really don't know how to print to the vfp, as it is it prints in $ and I need it in R$

vfp:

```
<td id="td0"><apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}">
<apex:param value="{!produto.TotalPrice}" />
</apex:outputText></td>

Controller:
 public static String formatarValorMoeda(Decimal valorFormatar){
        if(String.valueOf(valorFormatar).contains(',')){
            valorFormatar.setScale(2);
        }
        String centavos = ((valorFormatar - Math.floor(valorFormatar)) == 0) ? ',00' : '';
        List<String> args = new List<String>{'0','number','###.###.###.###.##0'};
            String valorFormatado = String.format(valorFormatar.format(), args);
        
        if(String.valueOf(valorFormatado).contains(',')){
            List<String> aux = valorFormatado.split(',');
            if(aux.get(1).length() == 1){
                String temp = aux.get(1);
                aux.remove(1);
                aux.add(','+temp + '0');
                valorFormatado = aux.get(0)+aux.get(1);
            }
        }
        return valorFormatado + centavos;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this (note the `R$` as part of the value of the `outputText`:

```
<apex:outputText value="R$ {0, Number, ###.###.###.###.##0}">
   <apex:param value="{!produto.TotalPrice}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

and then it is not clear why you need the controller method at all